# ArrayList through class

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

I'm doing an assignment, and I'm just wondering if it is possible to reference (If that is the right word?) a class through an ArrayList. Like in Java you would just do

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

Is it possible to do something like this in Visual Basic?

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class A

End Class

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim list() as New List(of A)
        list.Add(New A())
    End Sub
End Class
```

.NET does have an `ArrayList` class, but it was essentially rendered obsolete with the advent of generics.

EDIT: Derp, you tagged the question VB.Net, not C#... updated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its easy to do.

`Dim somearray() as new array(of objectType)`